# C++ template type and type of template

Tags: c++, templates

What is the type of `T` if I write something like that:

```
template<typename T>
class AClass{
  private:
    T member;
  public:
    AClass(const T& value = T()) : member(value) {}
}; 

int main(){
  const char* n = "Hello";
  AClass<char*> a(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Does `T` refers to a `char` or a pointer over a `char`?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: What's `Aclass`, and how, if at all, is it related to `AClass`?

Comment: It will not compile.

Comment: @Eugene, sorry, now it compiles.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Aclass is a typo.

Comment: Well, within the specialization `AClass<char*>`, `T` stands for `char*`, of course. I suppose I don't really understand the question.

Comment: `char* n = "Hello";` is not valid C++ and it is probably accepted as a non-standard compiler extension. It needs to be `const char* n = "Hello";` instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I am quite confused with templates. I just wanted to know  if T is a pointer to char in the above statements. I thought that if I needed T to be a pointer, I had to write `T* member`.

Comment: Again, within the specialization `AClass<char*>`, `T` names the type `char*`. Think of it roughly as if there were a  `typedef char* T;`.

Comment: Thanks, its clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts:

- `T` is `char *` in your example
- The example [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/g/QOQvJc)

Think about your constructor:

```
AClass(const T& value = T())
```

What you want is a pointer to `const char`, that is `const char *`.
In your constructor you are saying that `T` is `const`, thus you are asking for a `const` pointer to `char`, that is `char * const`.
They are actually two different beasts and the compiler complains about the lack of a `const` (let me say) *in the right place* in your constructor. That's because a conversion from `const char *` to `char *` is not allowed.

Comment: Weird, it compiles well under MSVC2015.

Comment: I tested under linux with g++ 4.9.2 and yes, it won't compile for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to write

`AClass<char*> a('n');`

`T` is a `char*` (address), but `'n'` would resolve to simply `char`.  I don't believe it would compile.

Comment: It has been fixed

Comment: This should be a comment.